# Runtime complexity of recursion inside loop

Tags: java, recursion, runtime

I try to determine the runtime complexity of the following code. I came up with `T(n) = n * T(n-1) + n` where `T(0) = 1` but not sure if it's correct and how to solve it.

```
private void myFunction(int[] nums, int startIndex, int target) {
    if (target == 0) {
        // do something
    }
    if (target <= 0 || start > nums.length) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = startIndex; i < nums.length; i++) {
        myFunction(nums, i+1, target-nums[i]);
    }
}

myFunction(nums, 0, target);
```

Comment: Sounds correct, more or less

Comment: Aheum, I don't get the +n

Comment: In the function why do you require so many parameters? please put some comments to the code

Answer (score 0):

I guess the recurrence relation for the function is 
T(n) = n * T(n-1) + O(1), where T(0) = 1

**Reduction:**

```
T(n) 
= n * T(n-1) + O(1)
= n * (n-1) * T(n-2) + 1 + 1
= n * (n-1) * (n-2) * T(n-3) + 1 + 1 + 1
...
= n * (n-1) * (n-2) * (n-3) ... T(0) + n * 1 (n times)
= n! + n
```

Hence, the overall complexity for the function is **O(n!)** which is greater O(2<sup>n</sup>). [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation/487278#487278).

Hope it helps!